# The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine? VBScript

Tags: database, oracle, vbscript, oracle11g

I am attempting to connect to a DB in a VBScript application I am writing and this is the error I get upon trying to connect.

The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

I attempted to register OraOLEDB11.dll by doing the following in cmd ran as admin:

```
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe \path\to\dll\OraOLEDB11.dll
```

A dialog popped us indicating it successfully registered, but the error remained, so I did more research and found that for 32-bit dll files, you must do:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe \path\to\dll\OraOLEDB11.dll
```

Same result, got a dialog saying success, but the error persists.

Not sure what to try at this point. I've seen some people say to install both 32 and 64 bit versions but I want to see if there's anything else I can try before doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The architecture has to match all cases, i.e. all following must be the same either 32 bit or 64 bit, you cannot mix any.

- The VBScript interpreter (`%windir%\System32\cscript.exe` vs. `%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe`)
- `%windir%\System32\regsvr32.exe` vs. `%windir%\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`
- The DLL `OraOLEDB11.dll` you want to register
- The installed Oracle Client

Just a note, it does not matter whether your Oracle **Database** is 32 or 64 bit.

You have to install both 32 and 64 bit versions of Oracle client only if you require to use either of them.

When you run your VBScript by simple double-click on it, then it will run in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Visual Studio, Just check the Build platform (Active Solution Platform)  is **Any CPU** then change it to "**x86**" it will work.

If still not working then check for your Oracle is 32 bit or not, If not then install 32 bit